# How do I catch the SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java

Say I have a socket variable called SuperSocket is there any way that I can catch the timeout exception ?

```
       SuperSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);

       catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
        System.out.println("Timeout");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: You *are* catching it. What's the question here?

Comment: My Spidey Sense is telling me the OP doesn't understand what `setSoTimeout` does, and that you would have to **do** something with the `Socket` that could possibly time out and throw that exception before you'd be able to catch it.

Comment: @BrianRoach Probably a good enough guess. I don't bother, myself.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to not understand what `setSoTimeout()` does and when that exception would be thrown.

From the Javadoc: ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html )

> public void setSoTimeout(int timeout)
>                            throws SocketException
>
> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
>   With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this
>   amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero
>   is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

The only time a `SocketTimeoutException` can be thrown (and then caught) is when you're doing a blocking read on the `Socket`'s underlying `InputStream` and no data is received in the specified time (causing the read to ... time out).

```
superSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
InputStream is = superSocket.getInputStream();
int i;
try {
    i = is.read();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
    System.out.println("I timed out!");
}
```

**Edit to add:** There's actually one other time the exception can be thrown, and that's if you're calling the two argument version of `Socket.connect()` where you supply a timeout.

Comment: how would you handle the connection timeout versus the read timeout separately?