# I can't catch SocketTimeoutException()

Tags: java, sockets, exception, client, server

SOLUTION: See my answer down below

I have a Server/Client Chat Application, where the Clients are communicating using P2P (each has a little server inside). So each Client has a Thread which should constantly monitor if a message came in on any of the connected Sockets (= other Clients). But because the readLine() methode from BufferedReader blocks, I want to break it using SocketTimeoutException, so that every Socket gets monitored for a brief moment, and then it switches to the next.

```
Socket tmp = add.getSocket();
try{
  tmp.setSoTimeout(2000);
  Communication com = new Communication(tmp);
  System.out.println(com.get());
} catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
  if(!running)return;
} catch(SocketException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

( -- A Communication gets a Socket and manages the InputStreams of said Socket. com.get() is
just a method which calls in.readLine() where in is the BufferedReader of the InputStream --)

But the compiler says that there is never a SocketTimeoutException thrown in the try Block.
If I don't catch the exception, however, after said Timeout I get the SocketTimeoutException.
I have no idea on how to fix this

EDIT:

The get() Methode

```
 public String get() throws SocketTimeoutException {
                String str = null;
                try{
                        if(s.isClosed()==false) str =  in.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e){
                         if(e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                                 throw new SocketTimeoutException();
                        }
                         e.printStackTrace();
                }
                        return str;
        }


java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at Communication.get(Communication.java:46)
    at ListeningThread.run(ListeningThread.java:26)
```

ListeningThread.run() is the function the first code snippet is embedded in.
Line 26 is the line

```
System.out.println(com.get());
```

Comment: Please show code that throws `SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: The code in the comment you just removed can never actually throw `SocketTimeoutException`, even thought it's declared to do so. By catching `IOException` it is catching `SocketTimeoutException` as well.

Comment: possible duplicate ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736899/how-do-i-catch-the-sockettimeoutexception

Comment: `ConnectException` extends `SocketTimeOutException` and this question has an eloquent answer on the same issue http://goo.gl/OYfFJW

Comment: I edited the methode in the original post. @EJP is there any way that I can break the readLine() lock in another way besides throwing SocketTimeoutException? How do I catch a SocketTimeoutException caused by read() other than how I'm trying to?

Comment: You can check if the getCause() on the IOException is an instance of SocketTimeoutException

Comment: And shouldn't the readLine() method itself throw a SocketTimeoutException after the time has run out?

Comment: You should check the javadoc for readLine(). Does it say so ?

Comment: @ramp No but then I don't get what setSoTimeout is supposed to do. I thought it breaks the read() lock after the timeout, and if it does, where can I catch the exception? With ServerSocket and the timeout on accept() it worked perfectly fine

Comment: It surely will. That's what timeout means. What is confusing I think, is the manner in which it propagates the exception for those who want to handle it. I have not tried it out myself, but I think it creates a SocketTimeoutException, wraps it in IOException and throws it back. And I think that's how it should be, because the setSoTimeout() itself does not throw the exception, it is the read that does it. How does the read() know that a timeout has been set on the Socket?

Comment: That sounds like an idea worth checking out. You mentioned testing if e.getCause() is a SocketTimeoutException, I tried it but I don't know exactly how to compare a Throwable to an Exception (equals as well as == didn't work for me for some reason)

Comment: if(e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException){...}

Comment: I did that and in case of e beeing a SocketTimeoutException i throw a new SocketTimeoutException. But I still have the same problem that the thrown Exception doesn't get caught by the try{} block

Comment: try{
                    if(s.isClosed()==false) str =  in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e){  
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    try{
   if(e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
    throw new SocketTimeoutException();
   }
      catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
   //do whatever
                    }
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocketTimeoutException extends InterruptedIOException which extends IOException.
So, as EJP said, if this exception is thrown, catch block of get method will catch it.

Comment: So I checked if the IOException is instanceof SocketTimeoutException and if so then throw a new SocketTimeoutException. But still, the catch block doesn't catch it

Comment: Can you put the code snippet which you used for this modification?

Comment: Can you also attach the exception log?

Comment: Just to be sure that this stacktrace coming from IOException catch block, just print some message in sysout instead of stacktrace and share the result.For eg: catch(IOException ex){System.out.println("In IOExcpetion block");} Also do the same for other catch block.

Comment: the "instanceof" if-block doesn't get entered

Comment: Use ex instanceof SocketTimeoutExcpetion instead of ex.getCause() in catch block

Comment: Okay know the IO Block gets entered, then the exception is printed(the same as above) but then the "e instanceof ..." block gets entered?

Comment: getCause method is used to the get the exception which caused this exception adn so on. Here no exception is causing this exception there e.getCause is returning null.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Like I said, i changed it to "ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException" but know I get the result I posted

Comment: No I don't want to return. This thread gets a list of Sockets I connected to. Now it should listen on each Socket for a few moments and then go on to the next. This is why I want to break the readLine() after x milliseconds, to go on in the loop if there are no incoming messages

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the exception is now gone!
This is the updated get() function:

```
    public String get() throws SocketTimeoutException {
            String str = null;
            try{
                    if(s.isClosed()==false) str =  in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e){
                    try{
                            if(e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                                    throw new SocketTimeoutException();
                            }
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException f){
                    }
            }
                    return str;
    }
```

Notice the lack of e.printStackTrace() before the second try{} block. Thanks to everybody who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

MIght be completely al-together different issue, but one common/minor issue with below code

```
catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
  if(!running)return;
}
```

With this piece of code, you won't see the exception even if it occurs. This is called swallowing of exception. Display `e.printStackTrace` to get the exception in the output.

Comment: What I want is to "break" the block of readLine(), maybe ending the program using return